# Console output different from python script output

Tags: python, sorting, console

Python student here.

I am running some tests on sorting and using basic simultaneous assignment.
This is my 1st time running into this sort of issue.
When i run the code line by line in the console, I get a different result from when I run under a .py script.

Console code & result (what I expect)

```
>>> a = [16, 3, 5, 5, 21, 13, 25, 15, 7]
>>> for i in range(len(a)-2, -1, -1):
...     if a[i] > a[i+1]:
...         a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i]
...
>>> print(a)
[3, 16, 5, 5, 7, 21, 13, 25, 15]
>>>
```

Script

```
a = [16, 3, 5, 5, 21, 13, 25, 15, 7]
for i in range(len(a)-2, -1, -1):
    if a[i] > a[i+1]:
        a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[1]
print(a)
```

Script result(what I DO NOT expect)
saved as 'testing_sort.py'
run as 'python3 testing_sort.py'

```
[3, 3, 5, 5, 7, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: You have a type in the last line , a[1] must be , a[i].

Comment: wow! I tried it and it really does that... now I got curious too...

Comment: Ohh yesss... wow I just copied the code assuming it's the same. I think you just had a typo on your `line` `4`

Comment: Oooops!! Darn it, and i thought i had checked it properly. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at your code in testing_sort.py Line 4, you are not swapping `a[i]` with `a[i+1]`, you replaced `a[i]` with `a[i+1]` and `a[i+1]` with `a[1]`.
replace `a[1]` with `a[i]`.

Comment: It's fine. I would advise you to just print the variables in between, that would save you time and confusion.